# how to calculate monthly budget till current day in power bi Desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I have a budget broken down by month. But I need to calculate it till current day. 
For example :

```
    Budget**        PostDate**
Jan  $2,125,889     1/1/2018
Feb  $4,141,659     2/1/2018
Mar  $4,320,698     3/1/2018
Apr  $4,461,430     4/1/2018
May  $4,049,404     5/1/2018
     $19,099,080
```

The total below is $ 19,099,080 for the whole 5 month of this year. 
What I need is:

1) calculate the budget per day for current month
         4,094,404 / 31 = 132,077.548

2) calculate how many days already passed in current month:

```
     difference in days between the beginning of the month and today. = 24
```

3) calculate budget through current day in current month:

```
     Budget Per Day * Days passed in this month = 132,077.548 * 24 = 
$ 3,169,861
```

4) Sum up budget for previous 4 month and Budget through current day:

```
    15,049,676 + 3,169,861 = 18,219,537
```

Also I have a Year parameter in my report. 
So the numbers should change depending on a year.

[image]

I am trying to make it in one measure using variables.
I was able to get number of days in current month:

```
VAR DaysInCurrentMonth = 
        MAXX(Dates, DAY(EOMONTH(Dates[Date], 0)))
```

I am stuck on how to get number of days passes in this month. How to substitute "BegginingOfMonth" with the date so I can utilize DATEDIFF function.

VAR DaysPassed=DATEDIFF ( "BegginingOfMonth", EOMONTH ( NOW (), 0 ), DAY )

Also tried to use `DATE` function, but the year will be dynamic. It wont let me use a year from date table.

UPDATE:

Alexis, thanks for your respond. Simple and clear. 
The only thing it summarizes till the end of the year, is any way to get sum only till current day?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a month-to-date measure that should add up correctly:

```
MTD Budget = SUMX(Budget,
                  Budget[Budget] *
                  IF(MONTH(TODAY()) <= MONTH(Budget[PostDate], 1, BLANK()) *
                  IF(MONTH(TODAY()) = MONTH(Budget[PostDate]),
                     DIVIDE(DAY(TODAY()), DAY(EOMONTH(Budget[PostDate],0))), 1))
```

This pro-rates the budget only for the current month.

Comment: Alexis thank you. I updated question. It gives me total for the whole year. What would be the way to only get in till current day?

Comment: You can just add a condition to the product. See my edit.

Comment: Great. Just instead of `<=` need to be  `>=`.  Thank you very much!